# Confusion during proof of $\limsup(X_n / \log n) = 1$ a.s for exponential distribution

Tags: probability-theory

I have the following proof of $\limsup(X_n / \log n) = 1$ almost surely,
where $X_n$ are i.i.d. exponential random variables. ($P(X_n > x) = e^{-x}$)

---

We have
$$ P(X_n > c \log n) = \frac{1}{n^c}$$
Considering convergence of the series,
$\sum_n P(X_n > c \log n) < \infty$ if $c > 1$
while $\sum_n P(X_n > c \log n) = \infty$ if $c \leq 1$.

By Borel-Cantelli lemma,
$P(X_n > c \log n \textrm{, infinitely often }) = 0$ for $c > 1$.

By second Borel-Cantelli lemma,
$P(X_n > c \log n \textrm{, infinitely often }) = 1$ for $c \leq 1$.

After rewriting to get $\limsup$ involved, it is easy to obtain $\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{X_n}{\log n} = 1$.

---

Here comes the problem, though. Consider event
$$A_k := \{ X_n > (1 + 1/k) \log n \textrm{, infinitely often } \}$$
Clearly, $A_k$ is an increasing sequence of events, whose union is
$$A := \{ X_n > 1 \log n \textrm{, infinitely often } \}$$
Thus $A_k \uparrow A$, so I expect $P(A) = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} P(A_k)$.
However, we showed that $P(A_k) = 0$ while $P(A) = 1$, which contradicts the limit.

I am confused here. Which part has gone wrong? Or did I misinterpret some theorem?

Comment: I can see $\bigcup A_k \subseteq A$, but I don't see the converse. If $X(\omega) > \log n$ for infinitely many $n$, why do the values have to be bounded by some factor of $1+1/k$?

Comment: Yep, that was the hole in my logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true that the sequence $(A_k)$ is increasing, but its union is not $A$.
For example, letting $Y_n=X_n/(\log n)-1$, the inclusion
$$\bigcap_{n\geqslant 2}\{Y_n\in (1/(n+2), 1/(n-1)\}\subset A$$
takes place, but we not do not have
$$\bigcap_{n\geqslant 2}\{Y_n\in (1/(n+2), 1/(n-1)\}\subset \bigcup_{k\geqslant 1} A_k.$$

Comment: Thank you, it seems like "infinitely often" part got me. I guess I need to be more careful in probability theory..

Comment: I am worried if this one is also false then:  Let $B_N := \{ sup X_n > N \}$, $B := \{ sup X_n = \infty \}$. Do I have $\cap_N B_N = B$?

Comment: @Abastro That should be fine. $\sup X_n (\omega) > N$ for all $N$ implies $\omega\in B$. Converse is also clear.